# Cannot get Plaid sandbox to work on iOS with Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-connect, plaid

When I use the un:user_good and pw:pass_good I get the attached screen

And it does not return a accessToken
I have already added my public key in my AppDelegate

```
   [![@IBAction fu][1]][1]nc plaidConnectButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let plaidLink = PLDLinkNavigationViewController(environment: .tartan, product: .connect)!

    plaidLink.linkDelegate = self
    plaidLink.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = true
    plaidLink.definesPresentationContext = true
    plaidLink.modalPresentationStyle = .custom

    self.present(plaidLink, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


func linkNavigationContoller(_ navigationController: PLDLinkNavigationViewController!, didFinishWithAccessToken accessToken: String!) {
    print("success \(accessToken)")
    myAPIClient.connectAddBank(bankToken: accessToken, completion:{
        (error) in
        if(error != nil) {
            print(error.debugDescription)
        } else {
            print("successfully added bank")
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    })

}

func linkNavigationControllerDidFinish(withBankNotListed navigationController: PLDLinkNavigationViewController!) {
    print("Manually enter bank info?")
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unlistedBankSegue", sender: self)
}

func linkNavigationControllerDidCancel(_ navigationController: PLDLinkNavigationViewController!) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Set your environment to **.sandbox** during the init process.

Plaid support link for this: https://github.com/plaid/link/issues/140